# Kendo UI Grid Detail Template in Declarative Initialization

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to bring about a grid with a detail template using declarative initialization. I would appreciate if someone tells me why the details template in the code below is not working. Here's the fiddle I use: http://jsfiddle.net/SiddharthSD2/5MU4r/76/

```
    <div id="demo-grid" data-role="grid"
    data-bind="source: people" data-columns='[
            {"field": "name", 
             "title": "Full Name"
             },
            {"field":"phone", "title":"Phone"}]'
     data-details-template="detail-template"

></div>

<script id="detail-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <div>
        <span>Phone Number for #=name#:</span>
        <span data-bind="text: phone" />
        <input data-bind="value: phone" />
    </div>
</script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
      {name: "Joe", phone: "212-555-1234"}, 
      {name: "Sally", phone: "212-999-7785"},
      {name: "Bill", phone: "212-244-7035"}
  ]
});

// Create an observable object.
var vm = kendo.observable({
    people: ds,
});
kendo.bind($("#demo-grid"),vm);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not `data-details-template="detail-template"` but `data-detail-template="detail-template"` (singular *detail*).

Your JSFiddle modified here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/5MU4r/77/